# Private Relay Emails: actions and list different between iPhone Settings and iCloud.com

Tags: icloud, email, icloud-plus

I set up a private relay Hide My Email address for a website which double-checks addresses and orders for purchases, using surveys sent to the address. I've received a few of them, and successfully purchased and received products, but it's been irritating having to work around the Private Relay address. I've had enough issues with the surveys sometimes not sending, and having to manually copy the private relay address into email fields that I decided to simply disable the Private Email; I double-checked that [disabled emails can be re-activated](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mm3adb030cbf/icloud) (in case anything went wrong), went into my Settings on my phone and hit 'Stop Using Apple ID'. Then I logged back into the website, and chose to use my actual email. That worked fine.

Unfortunately, there's one last purchase on this website already set up with the Private Relay email, which can't be changed for security reasons. No problem, I thought, going back to the Settings on my iPhone, I'll simply reactivate it. The email address was gone, with no option to reactivate. I get slightly concerned, and go to iCloud.com, and go to Hide My Emails. No email addresses. That *can't* be right, because I have loads of other Hide My Email addresses still in use.

So, it seems like creating Hide My Email addresses on iPhone > Settings > iCloud is different to creating Hide My Email addresses on iCloud.com, despite them both using the same Apple ID? And also apparently Private Relay emails made in iPhone Settings cannot be reactivated for some reason? [This article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212519), for instance, doesn't say anything about reactivating emails.

Having read three different Apple articles with practically identical names, I found myself back on [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mm3adb030cbf/icloud) which I only now notice implies, but doesn't state outright, that Hide My Email addresses can only be *temporarily disabled* via iCloud.com, and the option on the iPhone Settings (unhelpfully labeled 'Stop using Apple ID') deactivates it entirely, with no explanation of the difference. I didn't even notice, since it's discussing the same Hide My Email system and iCloud+, both of which are available both on iPhone and iCloud.com, and without it being obviously stated, or, in my opinion, reasonable to assume, that Private Relay addresses can only be temporarily disabled on the website.

Firstly, **is there a reason for this inability to temporarily disable an address via iPhone Settings?** It seems genuinely absurd to me that you need to log into the website to do this one thing, when the iCloud section of Settings is basically designed so that these things can be done from the Settings app. This is made more annoying by the fact that on the iPhone Settings, the term used is 'Stop using Apple ID', something which is vague enough to cover both temporarily disabling and permanently deleting the email, with no explanation of which it is. Clicking 'Stop using Apple ID' brings up another confirmation box, but it only says 'Next time that you use this app, you may be asked to create a new account.' (Most of this point is just me complaining about the system, I'm aware.)

Secondly, **is there a reason why iCloud.com and my iPhone Settings have two different lists of Hide My Email addresses** (iCloud.com having none, iPhone Settings having numerous), **despite them both supposedly using the same Apple ID and iCloud account?**

And finally (though probably most practically important) **is there a means of reactivating the Private Relay address** (which I still have noted down) if it was 'Stop Using'ed on iPhone?